# Features&labels from CSV using CsvDataset for model.fit in tf.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I try to use CsvDataset([tf.contrib.data.CsvDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/CsvDataset)) to represent features and labels of a dataset.

```
#download Iris data
TRAIN_URL = "http://download.tensorflow.org/data/iris_training.csv"
train_path_x = tf.keras.utils.get_file(TRAIN_URL.split('/')[-1], TRAIN_URL)
```

In concrete using this line[Iris dataset use, 4-float and 1-int, representing features and labels]:

```
csv_dataset = tf.contrib.data.CsvDataset(train_path_x, [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.int64], header=True, select_cols=[0,1,2,3,4])
```

To validate the information I used this:

```
interator = csv_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  while True:
    try:
      print(sess.run(interator))
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
      break
```

But if I try to use the tf.keras sequential model for this dataset, I need **x** and **y** elements or **features** and **labels**

```
model.fit()
```

I think I need to implement a **parse_function** and **map** method for the dataset before **make_one_shot_iterator** like the method used tf.data.TextLineDataset or tf.data.TFRecordDataset

something like that:

```
features, label = csv_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
model.fit(x=features, y=label, steps_per_epoch=8, epochs=200, verbose=1)
```

but I'm not sure, any ideas?